# Using Zorn's lemma to find a minimal subset of measure $1$?

Tags: measure-theory

I'm confused about a use of Zorn's lemma that seems to give a contradiction.

Suppose $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ with measure $1$ partially ordered by inclusion.

If $A_0 \supset A_1 \supset \cdots $ is a decreasing sequence in $\mathcal{A}$ then $A:=\cap_k A_k\in \mathcal{A}$ since $m(A) = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} m(A_k) = 1$. So $A$ bounds the sequence below and by Zorn's lemma $\mathcal{A}$ has a minimal element $A'$.

But since points have measure $0$, $A'$ cannot be minimal since any point can be removed from $A'$ while maintaining a measure of $1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to apply Zorn's Lemma, you would have to consider **any** ordered set $I$ and an indexed collection of sets $\{A_i \mid i \in I\}$ such that $A_i \supset A_j$ whenever $i<j$, and each $A_i$ has measure $1$. You would then have have to prove that this collection of sets has a lower bound of measure $1$.

By restricting your attention only to the ordered set of natural numbers $I = \mathbb N$, you have not yet verified the hypotheses of Zorn's Lemma.

Answer (score 3):

This argument only works for countable intersections. For Zorn lemma you also have to consider uncountable ones.

Observe that if $A_x = [0,1]\backslash \{x\}$ for $x\in[0,1]$, then $\mu(A_x)=1$ for all $x$, but $\bigcap_x A_x = \emptyset$.